# Why is Neo4j returning a blank relationship?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to delete a relationship between two (2) nodes in Neo4j. I am clearly able to see the relationship exists as in the screencap below. But when I return the query as a table the relationship reference is showing blank ("empty"). Any idea why it is showing the relation as blank?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Which version of Neo4j are you using?

Comment: I am using neo4j 3.2.0

Answer (score 4):

I think you are just looking to return the `type` of the relationship.

The `empty` word in your results just means there are no attribute/value pairs on your relationship.

This behaviour changed in a more recent version of Neo4j. If you were to use the most recent version (3.3) you would receive an empty set `{ }` instead of the *`empty`* word in the result.

This query will return the type of the relationship in place of the `_empty_` word which may be what you expected.

```
MATCH (category:RuleTemplateCategory)-[relation:HAS_RULE_TEMPLATES]->(n:WTABaseRuleTemplate)
WHERE id(n) = 14609
RETURN type(relation), n, category
```

If you wanted to see a value there that is not the type of the relationship you could do something like this...

```
MATCH (category:RuleTemplateCategory)-[relation:HAS_RULE_TEMPLATES]->(n:WTABaseRuleTemplate)
WHERE id(n) = 14609
SET relation.type = "TEST"
RETURN type(relation), n, category
```

Comment: Hello Dave. I have tried querying by a relationship without attribute/value pairs using Neo4j 3.3.0 and the return value is an empty object ( `{}` ) and not the "empty" word.

Comment: Hi Bruno, i did notice that change some time recently in one of the last few releases. I expect that folks found `empty` confusing. I think the braces without any data is more consistent.

Comment: Right! So I thinks this is a good observation to point in your answer, you agree?

Comment: yep - agree, added a brief explanation

Comment: Hi I found another point here if I will return id(relation) it will give me the relationship id not a blank value, so the point is if relationship dont contains any value so it will show blank without considering id .